# SoapFormatter - Serialize out "clean" soap

Tags: c#, serialization, soap

I need to serialize out a composite object. I have a object "Trailer" that contains "Shipments" of "Items". When I serialize out the object using the SoapFormatter like so:

```
    Trailer trailer = new Trailer() { TrailerID = "1234" };
    Shipment shipment1 = new Shipment() { ShipmentNo = "123456789", CarrierCode = "1234", SupplierCode = "12345", CarrierProNo = "1234567", BillOfLadingNo = "11111111", DateNeeded = "2013-04-15", Loc = "000", PackageSlipNo = "11111111", OrderShipped = "2013-02-15", UnloadPriority = "", UpdateID = "" };
    shipment1.Items.Add(new Item() { ItemNo = "111111", ItemDescription = "Blah", ItemQty= "11", OrderNo = "1111111", OrderLineNo = "111" });
    shipment1.Items.Add(new Item() { ItemNo = "222222", ItemDescription = "Blah 2", ItemQty= "22", OrderNo = "2222", OrderLineNo = "2222" });
    trailer.Contents.Add(shipment1);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, trailer);

    string trailerSoapMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer());
```

I get this:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <Trailer id="ref-1">
        <TrailerID id="ref-2">1234</TrailerID>
        <Contents href="#ref-3"/>
     </Trailer>
     <a1:ArrayList id="ref-3" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/ns/System.Collections">
        <_items href="#ref-4"/>
        <_size>2</_size>
        <_version>2</_version>
        </a1:ArrayList>
        <SOAP-ENC:Array id="ref-4" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:anyType[4]">
        <item href="#ref-5"/>
        <item href="#ref-6"/>
     </SOAP-ENC:Array>
     <Shipment id="ref-5">
        <ASNNumber id="ref-7">123456789</ASNNumber>
        <SupplierCode id="ref-8">12345</SupplierCode>
        <Loc id="ref-9">000</Loc>
        <CarrierCode id="ref-10">12345</CarrierCode>
        <CarrierProNo id="ref-11">12223</CarrierProNo>
        <BillOfLadingNo href="#ref-7"/>
        <PackageSlipNo href="#ref-7"/>
        <UpdateID id="ref-12"></UpdateID>
        <UnloadPriority href="#ref-12"/>
        <DateNeeded id="ref-13">2013-03-15</DateNeeded>
        <OrderShipped id="ref-14">2013-02-15</OrderShipped>
        <Items href="#ref-15"/>
     </Shipment>
    .....
```

I would like a more structured message with Trailer as the top node containing shipments that contain items. I would also like to remove the id attributes added to the nodes and not have the ArrayList metadata serialized out. I realize that this is by design but I don't want/need the extra data. This maybe a case of using the wrong tool for the job.

Thanks

Comment: I figured out that you can use "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterTypeStyle.XsdString;" so that IDs aren't used but I am still getting ids for arrays of objects and am not getting a hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have my solution. I have decorated my Trailer class with MessageContract and decorated all properties with MessageBodyMember:

```
[MessageContract]
public class Trailer
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order=1)]
    public string TrailerID { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public List<Shipment> Contents { get; set; }

    public Trailer()
    {
        this.Contents = new  List<Shipment>();
    }
}

public class Shipment
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public string ASNNumber { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 2)]
    public string SupplierCode { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 3)]
    public string Loc { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 4)]
    public string CarrierCode { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 5)]
    public string CarrierProNo { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 6)]
    public string BillOfLadingNo { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 7)]
    public string PackageSlipNo { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 8)]
    public string UpdateID { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 9)]
    public string UnloadPriority { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 10)]
    public string DateNeeded { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 11)]
    public string OrderShipped { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 12)]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Shipment()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Item>();
    }
}

public class Item
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 2)]
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 3)]
    public string OrderLineNo { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 4)]
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 5)]
    public string ItemQty { get; set; }

    public Item() { }
}
```

I can then create a message like so:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message = System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.Default, "GetTrailerContents", trailer);
```